# Elastic. Find document whose child do not match the query

Tags: elasticsearch

In my project I have documents "Book" and "Chapter". Chapter is child of Book.
Chapter can have or not, field "subtitle". Inside one book, there can be chapters with or without subtitles.

Now I want to build a query to find all books, which have chapters with no subtitle defined. Defining subtitle with empty string, instead of not defining it, is not an option for me. Of course, if it wouldn't be a single option.

I've tried next:

```
"must_not" : [{
    "has_child" : {
       "query" : {
          "exists" : {
              "field" : "subtitle",
              "boost" : 1.0
           }
       }
    },......
}], 
"must" : [{
    "has_child" :{
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {
               "boost" : 1.0
           }
       }            
     }
 }....]...
```

But, obviously it will work only if child is single or all child do not have subtitle
matchAll needed to filter out books without chapters.

---UPDATE----

Mapping :

```
{
"book" : {
  "_all" : {
    "enabled" : false
  },
  "properties" : {
    "bookID" : {
      "type" : "integer"
    }, 
    "publicationDate" : {
      "type" : "date"
    },
    "author" : {
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
}


{
  "chapter" : {
    "_all" : {
       "enabled" : false
    },
    "_parent" : {
      "type" : "book"
    },
    "properties" : {
       "bookID" : {
          "type" : "integer"
       },
       "subtitle" : {
           "type" : "text"
       }
    }
}
```

So as example, I have 5 books. 1 one of them have no chapters at all,
2 - have 100% of chapters with sub title, 2 - others mixed. some chapters have subtitle, others - no.

I want in results get only two last books

Comment: Vadym, any chance you could post up your mapping and a small sample along with what you would want returned?

Comment: @Austio I've updated my question.
But this example with books/chapters is simplification of the real situation. my real mapping are much bigger, and have more sense from logical point of view ;)
But main problem is described here..
Thanks in advnace